# Does anyone know what cause this following error: (I use vercel to deploy my django code online)

Tags: django, github, subprocess, vercel, railway

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.│ exit code: 1╰─> [35 lines of output]/tmp/pip-build-env-l6u27ub6/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in setup.cfg!!

```
  \\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*
  The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.

  By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
  or your builds will no longer be supported.

  See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
  \\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*
```

!!parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)running egg_infowriting psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFOwriting dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txtwriting top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directorycontaining pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with theoption:

python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at<https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html\>).

[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.error: subprocess-exited-with-error

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.Traceback (most recent call last):File "/vercel/path0/manage.py", line 11, in mainfrom django.core.management import execute_from_command_lineModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:Traceback (most recent call last):File "/vercel/path0/manage.py", line 22, in <module>main()File "/vercel/path0/manage.py", line 13, in mainraise ImportError(ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?Error: Command "./build_files.sh" exited with 1

I have installed psycopg2-binary==2.9.6But it still doesnt't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.